# Filter with array in javascript for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have the following array:

```
var x = [{letter: 'A', number: 1}, {letter: 'B', number: 2}, {letter: 'C', number: 3}]
```

And I want to filter using this array:

```
var f = ['A', 'B']
```

So that my resulting array looks like this:

```
[{letter: 'A', number: 1}, {letter: 'B', number: 2}]
```

How can I accomplish this using javascript in AngularJS? I tried this, but no luck:

```
$filter('filter')(x, {letter: f});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use AngularJS's Filter module then you can do the following:

```
var x = [{letter: 'A', number: 1}, {letter: 'B', number: 2}, {letter: 'C', number: 3}]

var f = ['A', 'B']

function filterExp(value,index) {
  return (f.indexOf(value.letter) > -1)
}

$scope.filtered = $filter('filter')(x, filterExp, true);
```

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GordyD/v7ouhxsr/2/) to demonstrate its result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var filteredElems = x.filter(function(obj) {
    return f.indexOf(obj.letter) > -1
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5g6hjyzx/